# Quick and reliable solution for accessing Outlook 2011 .olm files on Windows Outlook

Tags: ms-office, windows

As I am currently using Outlook 2013 for Windows 8 and I have some crucial mails to access, which are in the form of Outlook für Mac-Archiv.olm and Harrison.olm in My Pen drive, I just carried out these mails from office PC and currently I am on holidays for 2 weeks, so please, its request for a reliable solution as soon as possible.

I will be extremely appreciated your assistance.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are looking for a Windows application able to read mail archives written by Outlook for Mac?

Comment: I do not believe it is currently possible to real "Outlook for Mac" archive files with Outlook on Windows. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Manually you can access your .olm files in Windows Outlook, but before the start of this files moving process,  you have to make some settings on your Outlook 2011 applications end, it’s essential to make changes in Outlook 2011, without making all these changes in Outlook 2011 you can’t get your .olm files on Windows Outlook,  as you have to configure your Mac Outlook 2011 with the IMAP mail account and have to follow below steps-

•   Firstly, set up an IMAP mail account (as an instance Gmail)

•   Afterward, configure your Mac Outlook 2011 with the IMAP mail account

•   Create a Gmail label to connect the IMAP mail account to Outlook 2011

•   Now, move all the emails from Outlook 2011 to the IMAP mailbox folder, after all the above steps to move all the data from IMAP mailbox folder to Windows Outlook.

Note: As per your query, you required quick response for .olm files to Outlook for Windows, you can try any software, at present multiple Free online software's are available for such conversion, you can utilized any of the application.

Hope the above information will assist you.

Comment: Thanks Mayra, your solution was good and assist me as well.